# Send a generated image in a Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I want to send a generated image in a Rails controller. Here is an exemple of code :

```
def image
  img = Magick::Image.new(130, 50)
  img.background_color = 'red'
  img.format = "PNG"
  send_data img.to_blob, :type => 'image/png', :disposition => 'inline'
end
```

This return an unreadable image.

Comment: Which ruby ? Which rails ? I don't see anything wrong in the code BTW.

Comment: Rails 4.0 and Ruby 1.9.3. Thanks to your question, I tried with 2.0.0 and it works. Thank you

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)